# Semantic UI Divider black bar

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, semantic-ui

I am having a problem with Semantic UI.  When I am adding a standard divider, the page is black where the divider should be, even though I have all the necessary files for it to work correctly. Here's the HTML mark-up for the divider:

```
<div class="ui horizontal divider"></div>
```

Which leaves me with the following result: [Black Box, Semantic-UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDBQ1.png)

Thanks for any help. Regards, Ashley.

Comment: Can you add a JS fiddle link with your code?

Comment: Have you tried putting text in the div ?

Comment: I'm not able to replicate this. Can you please post the code of your entire page or createa JSFiddle as Sarthak suggested?

Answer (score 0):

try using custom css to that element, height and width

```
width: 100%;
height: 1px;
```